# Extracting version number from a filename

Tags: linux, string, bash

I have a file in a folder like this:

> installer-x86_64-XXX.XX-diagnostic.run

where XXX.XX is a version number and I need the version number only. **How to do it in linux?**

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
current_ver=$(find /mnt/builds/current -name '*.run'|awk -F/ '{print $NF}')
```

So this gives me just the name of the file correctly (minus the location, which I don't want).

But how do I only get the XXX.XX version number into a variable such as `$version`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```
awk -F"-" '{ print $3 }'
```

With `-F` you specify the delimiter. In this case, `-`. The version number is the third field, so that's why you need `$3`.

Answer (score 7):

You actually don't need any external tools.  You can do this entirely within bash, by chopping variables according to patterns..

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ name="installer-x86_64-XXX.XX-diagnostic.run"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ vers=${name#*-}; echo $vers
x86_64-XXX.XX-diagnostic.run
[ghoti@pc ~]$ vers=${vers#*-}; echo $vers
XXX.XX-diagnostic.run
[ghoti@pc ~]$ vers=${vers%-*}; echo $vers
XXX.XX
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Or if you prefer, you can chop off pieces right-hand-side first:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ name="installer-x86_64-XXX.XX-diagnostic.run"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ vers=${name%-*}; echo $vers
installer-x86_64-XXX.XX
[ghoti@pc ~]$ vers=${vers##*-}; echo $vers
XXX.XX
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Of course, if you want to use external tools, that's fine too.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ name="installer-x86_64-XXX.XX-diagnostic.run"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ vers=$(awk -F- '{print $3}' <<<"$name")
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo $vers
XXX.XX
[ghoti@pc ~]$ vers=$(sed -ne 's/-[^-]*$//;s/.*-//;p' <<<"$name")
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo $vers
XXX.XX
[ghoti@pc ~]$ vers=$(cut -d- -f3 <<<"$name")
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo $vers
XXX.XX
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. This will come in handy.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
current_ver=$(find /mnt/builds/current -name '*.run'|grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing here with grep? Are you searching for integers with the [0-9] argument? What does -Eo do?

Comment: @AbeedSalam - read about grep's `-o` option.  It causes grep to output ONLY the bit that matched.  Can be very handy, though it gets even more useful in conjunction with `-P` (for preg, which is more functional than ERE).  Note that `grep -P` doesn't work in FreeBSD or OSX.  For FreeBSD, you need to install a different package that gives you `pcregrep`.

Comment: @AbeedSalam - yes the grep is matching integers surrounding a decimal point, so would pull out 100.456 for example

Answer (score 4):

People forget there is a simpler one, [`cut`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cut&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE).

```
$ echo "installer-x86_64-XXX.XX-diagnostic.run" | cut -d - -f 3
XXX.XX
```

Comment: So when to use cut and when to use awk?

Comment: @AbeedSalam, `cut` does this task, that's splitting a line in this case, and it does it right. `awk`, for instance, does more than just this. If I need to choose between the two to do this same task, I'd go with `cut` and that's keeping it simple